# Higher-kinder types inference

Tags: scala, type-inference, typechecking

(Scala 2.11.8)

Consider the following snippet:

```
class Case2 {
  trait Container[+A] {
    def addAll[B >: A, T2 <: Container[B]](that: T2): Boolean
  }

  def t1: Container[String] = ???
  def t2: Container[Int] = ???

  // Works
  t1.addAll[Any, Container[Any]](t2)

  // Errors:
  //* type mismatch; found : Case2.this.Container[Int] required: T2
  //* inferred type arguments [String,Case2.this.Container[Int]] do not conform to method addAll's type parameter bounds [B >: String,T2 <: Case2.this.Container[B]]
  t1.addAll(t2)
}
```

Why can't last `addAll` call inference the proper least common supertype?

Comment: Not an answer, but do you actually need the `T2`? `def addAll[B >: A](that: Container[B]): Boolean` should work and is more like what you usually see in this kind of situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, In real code there are type constraints dependent on `T2`, so I don't think that's possible. Snippet above is a simplification I came up with while investigating a problem in the original code.

Comment: It seems that you are, in effect, asserting that `Container[Int] <: Container[B] ` where `B >: String`. If you explicitly set B to Any, it will work (as you found) but I don't think the type inference system is allowed to substitute Any as a "solution". I'm not 100% sure of that, though.

Comment: I'm explicitly defining `trait Container[+A]` to be covariant, so in my understanding this should be inferable. Also, the issue persists with any least common denominator, not just `Any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a [ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10188), which was closed as being "out of scope"
Quote by [Adriaan Moors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276895/adriaan-moors):

> Type inference does not support bounds that refer to other type parameters.